# OpenId DotnetOpenAuth Classic ASP Support

Tags: asp-classic, openid, dotnetopenauth

My website is in classic ASP. Want to implement openId relying party so using the DotNetOpenAuth.dll

Tried the asp.net WebForm and MVC sample. Both straight froward and works great.

After a bit of struggle i run the classic ASP Sample provided by DotNetOpenAuth.

With WebForms & MVC  i tried test with google, google profiles, yahoo/flickr, wordpress, blogspot, myopenid, etc works well

When tried with classic asp Only google, profiles, yahoo/flickr works well. For others like myopenid, blogspot, & wordpess it says openid not found. but it work well with webforms & MVC.

My question is that, for calssic ASP Is there anything like it support only direct openid provider like yahoo/google or am i missing anything.

I am using the sample from dotnetopenauth. Nothing special.

Regards,
Pradeep.

Comment: Seems like MyOpenID is kaput! Not fun!

Comment: myopenid seems healthy to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is some information in this thread that may be useful....

http://groups.google.com/group/dotnetopenid/browse_thread/thread/abcf1439d8b87c44/60b195b36b0207f4

Answer (score -1):

Underneath it's the exact same engine powering OpenID for both classic ASP and ASP.NET.  Aside from possible configuration differences, which I'm not aware of any.  You may attach a managed debugger to the IIS process and download the DNOA source code matching your version to step through and find out what's going wrong.